# Plotting a Graph with multiple data values using Numpy and Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm an undergraduate chemistry student and atm we're doing a python module in the course. I need to complete my formative assignment but I'm a bit confused about how to go about plotting the graph, here's my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
os.chdir("C:\Users\Chloe\Desktop")
data=np.loadtxt("tree_rings.txt")
for column in data.T:
    plt.plot(data[:,0],column)
plt.show()
```

This is mostly from some extensive googling and looking at the powerpoints put out by my lecturers haha.
The problem I'm having is that the graph shows the x variable as if it's a line on the graph if that makes sense. The x axis is the year and the y axis is the size of tree rings, it plots the years as a line on the graph, is there a way to stop this from showing on the graph, everything else seems to be fine though, thanks in advance :)
EDIT:

[image]

This is what the graph comes out as, I expected it to come out without the blue line at the top. The rest of it is as expected. The blue line looks like it represents the year which is what I have as my x axis. Also there are 3 sets of data to plot (so I was expecting 3 lines), the size of rings in samples 1,2 and 3 plotted against the year. I'm also extremely new to python so mostly just in the stages of figuring things out.

Comment: Are you sure you need a `for` loop there? I think you should try to extract *once* the X and Y arrays from your text file then `plt.plot(X, Y)`.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what you've tried, what the result was and what you expected (what you describe in the second paragraph)? It would also be helpful to include all of the code need to run your example (for instance) it looks like you've imported `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt`). If your question is complete it make giving an answer more efficient.

Comment: Use `for column in data.T[1:]:` to start drawing from the second column; the first column is your x-axis with the years, so the blue line is the x-axis versus itself

Answer (score 0):

The blue line comes from plotting the 'Year' data when you read the 'tree_rings.txt' data.

I guess that performance is not a big issue here (not dealing with huge data), so I will propose a not so efficient solution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
os.chdir("C:\Users\Chloe\Desktop")
data=np.loadtxt("tree_rings.txt")
skip_column = 0
counter = 0
for column in data.T:
    if counter == skip_column:
        continue
    counter += 1
    plt.plot(data[:,0],column)
plt.show()
```

If it doesn't skip the 'Year' column with this code, try changing the skip_column value and see if it works